# Unable to resolve image path from login.js

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm totally new to expo and react native
I'm trying to use ImageBackground 
I use it as the code below but I get this error "Unable to resolve "./assets/back.jpg" from "app\components\Login.js" "
My image is already in assets folder in my project
And also when I try to import font I get the same error
Does it need to import something before using or something else?
I also Tried it by not importing the image and adding the path directly to source property

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import back from './assets/back.jpg';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    AsyncStorage,
    Image,
    ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
export default class Login extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username:'',
            password:'',
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this._loadInitialState().done();
    }
    _loadInitialState = async () =>{
        var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        if (value !=null){
            this.prop.navigation.navigate('Profile');
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground source={back} style={styles.backImg}>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={styles.wrapper}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.logo}
                    source={require('/MyFirst/assets/logo.png')}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput} placeholder='Username'
                    onChangeText={(username) =>this.setState({username}) }
                    underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'
                        />
                        <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput} placeholder='Password'
                    onChangeText={(password) =>this.setState({password}) }
                    underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'
                        />
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}
                    onPress={this.login}>
                <Text style={styles.btnText}>Login</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </ImageBackground>

        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper:{
        flex:1,
    },
    container:{
        flex:1,
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        backgroundColor:'#e5ffd3',
        paddingLeft:40,
        paddingRight:40,
    },
    logo:{
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
    },
    textInput:{
        alignSelf:'stretch',
        padding:16,
        marginBottom:20,
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#d6d7da',
        borderRadius: 25,
    },
    btn:{
        alignSelf:'stretch',
        backgroundColor:'#589e25',
        padding:20,
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 25,
    },
    btnText:{
        color: '#ffffff',
    },
})
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './app/components/Login'
import Profile from './app/components/Profile'
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: Login},
    Profile: {screen: Profile},
});
const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ImageBackground` in this way. It will solve your problem

```
 <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/back.jpg')} style={styles.backImg}>
```

Working example can be found here [Link](https://snack.expo.io/@masukhelal/imagebackground)

Comment: remove the ```import back from './assets/back.jpg';``` this line. And check the import path. Add ```flex:1``` in the styles.backImg(If it isn't added).

Comment: Can you clean your cache and try again?

Comment: cleaned my cache and same error,do i have to link my image with something like npm link or expo link?

Comment: Go in this link for working example https://snack.expo.io/@masukhelal/imagebackground. I think your image path is wrong  I am updating my answer. Check it

Comment: Finally Worked , As you guessed problem was with addressing the image,Thanks alot